# compound assignment operator in java

Tags: java, operators

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;
int c = 10;

  a +=(a += b) + c; // this will be same as --> a = a+((a= a+b) +c);    
  /*                                                  2+((2=2+3)+10)
                                                   after adding 2+3
                                                   now value a = 5;
                                                    5 +((5)+10)
                                                    5 + (15)
                                                a = 20
 */
System.out.println("a: "+a); // a:17
```

when i execute above program the answer is `a:17` why not `a:20` ? 
according to me.
After resolving `(a += b)` now the value of  `a` should be `5` then `(a += b) + c` would be `15` and after that `a +=(a += b) + c;` should be `20` 
please help me understand thanks.

Comment: `a=a+(a=a+b)+c` maybe this makes it more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compound assignment operator stores the original value of the left operand before evaluating the second operand and performing the compound assignment (addition + assignment in this example).

Therefore

```
a += (a += b) + c;
```

is equivalent to :

```
int temp = a;
a = temp + (a += b) + c;
     2   +   2 + 3  + 10 = 17
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good example of where order of evaluation and precedence don't match. They usually do which makes it confusing when there is a difference, as you mention the expression is evaluated left to right like this

```
int s = a; // stack
int t = a + b; // second stack value.
s += t;
s += c;
a = t;
a = s;
```

Note the `(a+=b)` is the same as `(a+b)` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit tricky to understand. Although you have `a += b` on the right-hand side, that doesn't change the value of `a` that's used for the `+=` at the beginning of the expression; that will still be 2. E.g.:

```
a += (a += b) + c;
a = 2 + (a[still 2] += 3) + 10
a = 2 + (5) + 10
a = 17
```

The `a += b` on the right-hand side is really just a `a + b`, since this is all on the right-hand side of a `+=` already directed at `a`.

Details in [JLS§15.26.2: Compound Assignment Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2).

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can replace `a += b` with `a = a + b`. And *that* is very important.

Hence your expression is equivalent to

`a = a + (a = a + b) + c`

Note that this will be evaluated as `a = Term1 + Term2 + Term3` and in the order left to right.

`Term1` is 2.

`Term2` is the only tricky one. It is 5 (and has the side-effect of increasing `a` to 5 but that gets clobbered by the eventual assignment).

`Term3` is 10.

That recovers the total, 17.

Note that the behaviour of this expression in C and C++ is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

First you do a+=b so 2+3 you have 5. Then a+= your answer (here 5) so 2+=5 = 7. Then  7+10 = 17